# Can I use NUMERIC instead of BIGINT?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an old database table with column, which type is `BIGINT`. There's a lot of stored procedures and views that use that table and that column.

For some reason I need to change the type of that column to `NUMERIC(38,0)`.

Is it safe to do it? Should I cast in any stored procedure and view existing `BIGINT` to `NUMERIC(38,0)`?

Comment: You should bear in mind that any procedure that takes `bigint` as an argument or has a variable inside that is strictly correlated to `bigint` type and you change it - some may stop working. Same goes for query optimization inside functions. I think you should recreate your existing views after altering your column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

According to [this table on MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd424925.aspx) an `numeric(38,0)` has an higher capacity than a `bigint`.

I calculated the maximum values based on the numbers in the matrix:

> 9223372036854775808 (`bigint`, 2^63-1, 8 bytes)
>
> 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (`numeric(38,0)`, 10^38–1, 17 bytes)

Comment: I understand that. But, can I simply change the type of column from BIGINT to NUMERIC(38,0) or DECIMAL(38,0) without touching all stored procedures and views where old BIGINT column is used?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) for the possible conversions between data types.

Comment: @tesicg: Need more help?

Comment: I've taken a look at that table and it says there's an implicit conversion between numeric/decimal and bigint. As I understand, I could redefine that column to be numeric or decimal instead of bigint, but still not sure should I change stored procedures and views that reference that column.

Comment: It seems so it doesn't. You risk though that you end up with overflows, so it is better to have the same data types all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

According to me numeric data type is identical with decimal which represents a fixed precision number, which will scale numeric data from `-10^38 +1` through `10^38 –1`

I don't think that the number types you mention are using fixed precision number and therefore `BIGINT` is probably the most efficient way to store the number especially if you want to perform some computation in your application.

I don't see really any use for computation with those number and therefore you may even use a string of appropriate length which requires more space in the database but you may be able to allow grouping characters in the numbers.

using `BIGINT` datatype instead of string you can create efficient indexes.

As you write you're already using numeric datatype and therefore if you upgrade to SQL 2008R2 / 2012 you should consider switching to `BIGINT` as you don't need fraction in your number. The `BIGINT` data type is intended for use when integer values might exceed the range that is supported by the int data type.

EDIT:

You can change the data type from BIGINT to NUMERIC(38,0) but be ensure that a Arthimetic overflow error shouldn't occur while converting.

Comment: I need to change the type of column from BIGINT to NUMERIC(38,0) or DECIMAL(38,0) because it represents bar code.

Comment: I can't use BIGINT because bar codes can be 20 characters or more.

Comment: In that case you can change it